# Translating titles with ctex

Tags: languages, cjk, naming, xecjk

As best as I can understand, there are two ways to load the `ctex` package: as a document class (i.e. `\documentclass{ctexbook}` or as a package (i.e. `\usepackage{ctex}`). As I am using another document class, I have selected the later. This means, however, that the document uses English for titles throughout the document (e.g. table of contents, glossary).

When I try to rename the titles of parts of the documents, using `\CTEXoptions`, this always fails. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\CTEXoptions[contentsname={目录名}]
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{This is a chapter title}
\end{document}
```

This fails to compile:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `contentsname' undefined in families `CTEX'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                              
l.6 \CTEXoptions[contentsname={目录名}]
```

- How can I properly set the names of these items in my document?

> contentsname 目录名
>
> listfigurename 表格目录
>
> listtablename 插图目录
>
> figurename 图
>
> tablename 表
>
> abstractname 摘要
>
> indexname 索引
>
> bibname 参考文献

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the `ctexcap` package instead of `ctex`. This will automatically redefine the strings you mentioned in your question. The command `\CTEXoptions[contentsname={目录名}]` will also then work.

P/S: Surely 目录名 is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This is a long comment of LianTze Lim's answer.

- Load `ctexcap` package for other document classes. *But you should only load `ctexcap` for those document classes based on standard `article`, `report` and `book`*. For example, you can use `ctexcap` together with `extarticle` and `ltxdoc`, but you should NOT use `ctexcap` with `beamer`, `scrartcl` or `moderncv`. Actally `ctexcap` is rarely used.
  (EDIT: Well, it doesn't matter)
- You don't need to use `xeCJK` and `fontspec` explictly when you use `ctex` bundle.
- `目录名` should be `目录`.
- You are welcome to ask this kind of questions in [CTeX forum](http://bbs.ctex.org/).